# Prevent TinyMCE From Deleting <a> Tag Joomla

Tags: html, tinymce

I have an issue while using Joomla CMS and TinyMCE where it deletes my  tags that surround  which is essential for my layout.

I tried following some advice online but nothing seems to work and there's limited instructions for Joomla.

I really appreciate it and look forward to learning about this.

Code Entered

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 ">
    <div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle">
            <div>+</div></a>
            <div class="timeline-container">
                <a href="#" class="another-toggle">
                    <div>Link</div>
                    <p>
                        Text
                    </p>
                <a/>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Code After Saving

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 ">
    <div>
      <div>+</div>
        <div class="timeline-container">
          <div>Link</div>
           <p>Text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say I ever found a solution to this except to stop using the TinyMCE editor. I opted to just go forward with codemirror editor where necessary.